# Aliasing cd && echo doesn't work properly

Tags: command-line, bash, cd, alias, echo

I'm trying to create an alias that changes the directory and prints some content.

I've wrote this line:

```
alias test="cd ~/Documents/MyDir && echo 'content'"
```

The result is:

```
content
~$:~/Documents/MyDir
```

The expected result was:

```
~$:~/Documents/MyDir content
```

Comment: `test` is a [standard Unix/Linux command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) (used to test conditions, although its synonym `[` is a bit more commonly used). Making an alias that conflicts with it could cause weird problems; I recommend choosing a different name.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out but I haven't used `test` for the real alias, it was just an example.

Comment: that is strange, even for bashrc functions or joining two aliases, or inserting sleep between

Answer (score 3):

Unless additional detail gets added, what's below isn't a bad guess as to what is playing out.

First, a couple things to know:

- The `cd` command *itself* will not generate any output in your example; see the `cd` command in the Bash man page for the 2 conditions when it does generate output, neither of which applies here. (It's possible you or your sysadmin overrode the default setup so that it does, but let's assume not. You can check by running `type cd`; if you see `cd is a shell builtin`, then no override occurred.)
- When the shell needs input from you, it issues a prompt to let you know it's waiting on you. What it prints is determined by the value of a shell variable named `PS1`; you can see it by entering `echo "$PS1"`. Yours may be something along the lines of `~$:\w`  (the `\w` expands to your current directory; see the PROMPTING section in the Bash man page).

What happens when you enter `test` to invoke your alias:

1. The shell changes directory (probably generating no output), then
2. the shell echoes your `content`, then
3. having completed your instructions, the shell now prompts you to enter more input by printing your `PS1` variable.

... and that's why you're getting your unexpected results.

Last note: there is already a command named `test` in Unix/Linux; run `man test` to see what it does. Consider naming your alias `try`, or `albertotest`. :-)

Comment: Thank you! So, if I properly understood how things work, there's no chance to "freez" `content` and don't show `PS1` variable. To be clear, my purpose was to add something else after `content` (after it changed directory) and then run the command.

Comment: (Hoping to avoid a protracted back-and-forth in comments...) I'm not quite following, but it sounds like maybe you want your PS1 to dynamically vary (outputting something most times, or nothing occasionally). Explore having it run a function; see the `get_foo_version` stuff at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706538/getting-a-dynamic-bash-prompt-ps1-right) .